# Number of days between dates when you have entries with multiple dates

Tags: r, excel

I have a data set in which I need to calculate the days difference between the different dates and the initial date. To be more precise, here's a sample of the list:

```
date    page    count
23/01/2015  a   1
08/01/2015  b   514
09/01/2015  b   532
10/01/2015  b   175
11/01/2015  b   89
12/01/2015  b   113
13/01/2015  b   97
10/01/2015  c   373
11/01/2015  c   373
12/01/2015  c   315
13/01/2015  c   104
14/01/2015  c   52
15/01/2015  c   21
09/02/2015  d   13
10/02/2015  d   15
11/02/2015  d   6
12/02/2015  d   2
13/02/2015  d   5
14/02/2015  d   6
15/02/2015  d   6
```

What I want to achieve is to calculate the number of days between the first date in page "b" and the remaining days. So, for page "b", I'd now that the second entry is 1 day after the first date, the following entry 2 days, etc. The problem here is that I have different pages with different initial dates.

Thanks !

Comment: If you tag R and Excel, you should specify whether you work in excel or R, in order to receive appropriate answers

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>% 
    mutate(date = as.Date(date, format='%d/%m/%Y')) %>% 
    group_by(page) %>% 
    mutate(Diff= abs(as.numeric(date[1L]-date)))
```

Or a `base R` option would be

```
   unsplit(lapply(split(df2, df2$page), function(x) {
            Date <- as.Date(x$date, format='%d/%m/%Y')
           x$Diff <- as.numeric(Date-Date[1L])
           x  }), df2$page)
```

Comment: This also works with `min(date)` in place of `date[1L]`

Comment: @SamFirke Thanks, I thought about that, but the OP's dataset seems to be already sorted by date.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the `date` column to `"Date"` class and use `ave` to subtract the first `date` from each other `date` within `page`.  No packages are used.

```
DF$date <- as.Date(DF$date, "%d/%m/%Y")
transform(DF, offset = ave(as.numeric(date), page, FUN = function(x) x - x[1]))
```

If we knew that the dates within page are always consecutive then the last line could be simplified to:

```
transform(DF, offset = ave(count, page, FUN = seq_along) - 1)
```

In either case we get:

```
         date page count offset
1  2015-01-23    a     1      0
2  2015-01-08    b   514      0
3  2015-01-09    b   532      1
4  2015-01-10    b   175      2
5  2015-01-11    b    89      3
6  2015-01-12    b   113      4
7  2015-01-13    b    97      5
8  2015-01-10    c   373      0
9  2015-01-11    c   373      1
10 2015-01-12    c   315      2
11 2015-01-13    c   104      3
12 2015-01-14    c    52      4
13 2015-01-15    c    21      5
14 2015-02-09    d    13      0
15 2015-02-10    d    15      1
16 2015-02-11    d     6      2
17 2015-02-12    d     2      3
18 2015-02-13    d     5      4
19 2015-02-14    d     6      5
20 2015-02-15    d     6      6
```

**Note:**

We used this as `DF`:

```
Lines <- "date    page    count
23/01/2015  a   1
08/01/2015  b   514
09/01/2015  b   532
10/01/2015  b   175
11/01/2015  b   89
12/01/2015  b   113
13/01/2015  b   97
10/01/2015  c   373
11/01/2015  c   373
12/01/2015  c   315
13/01/2015  c   104
14/01/2015  c   52
15/01/2015  c   21
09/02/2015  d   13
10/02/2015  d   15
11/02/2015  d   6
12/02/2015  d   2
13/02/2015  d   5
14/02/2015  d   6
15/02/2015  d   6"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

In **Excel** if the dates start at A2 and the pages start at B2 then try this formula in D2 copied down

`=A2-INDEX(A$2:A2,MATCH(B2,B$2:B2,0))`

That uses `INDEX/MATCH` to find the first date for that page and subtracts the current date to give you the difference - for the first date for a page it will give you zero